# Clarification on creating Objects

Tags: java

This question might be a very simple question, but I am still kind of new to programming so please bear with me. 
If I have for example a class name picture and another class name simplePicture. 
Can I create a new object as: Picture a = new simplePicture();
So can I create an object using the constructor of another object? And if possible, how is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that if `SimplePicture` has been defined with the words `extends Picture` after the name.  That would make `SimplePicture` a subclass of `Picture`, which means that any `SimplePicture` is also a `Picture`, and that therefore all objects of class `SimplePicture` can be referred to with a variable of type `Picture`.

```
public class SimplePicture extends Picture {
    // ... put things here that are specific to SimplePicture
}
```

Comment: So I am guessing that if picture extends simplePicture, the object cannot be created the other way around.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: There was a type mismatch. So that means not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is only possible when there is a hierarchy.

```
 class SimplePicture extends Picture{

 }
```